# Ensure that generated yet checked-in files aren't rebuilt after git sync

Tags: git, makefile

I'm not sure whether this is a git question or a make question, or maybe both, but here goes...

Imagine you have a file `foo.cpp` which is generated by a generator program, `gen.py`. If the generator program is modified, it must be run again to generate a fresh version of `foo.cpp`.

A makefile rule that encodes this behavior could be as follows<sup>1</sup>:

```
foo.cpp: gen.py
    gen.py
```

For active development on `gen.py`, this is ideal I think.

However, consider the case where you make your project available remotely via git, say on github or some similar site. Users will download and make your project.

The traditional way of handing generated files is not to check them in all: don't include `foo.cpp` in git all (add it to your `.gitignore), and when the user builds your project, the file will be generated.

However, an alternately approach *is* to include the the generated file `foo.cpp` in git. This raises the possibility that `gen.py` and `foo.cpp` might be "out of sync"<sup>2</sup> if one is changed without updating the other but has a few other advantages:

- Users who just want to build the project but never update `gen.py` don't need to have the prerequisites to run `gen.py` (e.g., Python).
- The unmodified build is faster because the generation step doesn't run.
- You get direct feedback during staging/commit about what changes to `foo.cpp` are implied by `gen.py`, since the file will part of the diff.

I'm not interested in litigating the merits of checking in generated files versus always generating them locally. You may assume that for some project the decision has been taking to check in generated files, and this decision is not up for debate.

In that context then, my question is:

For a user who freshly clones a project, or who syncs a commit involving both files, how can I ensure that `make` doesn't try to generate `foo.cpp`? By default git will use current time when it syncs files, so the `foo.cpp` and `gen.py` will have the same timestamps, and `foo.cpp` will be rebuilt.

I can't ask users to change their git configuration.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps there would be additional dependencies for `foo.cpp` which would also appear as a prerequisite, but this is the "base case".

<sup>2</sup> A reasonable approach is to enforce that they are in sync via a git hook.

Comment: Couldn't you add a post-merge hook to `touch foo.cpp`?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the output and only update the target if it's different.  Say, for example, your `gen.py` will write it's output to stdout so normally you'd have a rule like this:

```
foo.cpp: gen.py
        ./gen.py > $@
```

You can change this to:

```
foo.cpp: gen.py
        ./gen.py > $@.tmp
        cmp -s $@ $@.tmp && rm -f $@.tmp || mv -f $@.tmp $@
```

The downside here is that until you *DO* update `foo.cpp` the `gen.py` recipe will always be run.  However no targets that *depend* on `foo.cpp` will be built, because its timestamp hasn't changed.

If that's expensive and you want to get around that you'll have to do something much more complicated: if the comparison is true (no difference) then you need to reset the timestamp on `gen.py` so that it's the same as the target; that ensures the target will no longer be considered out of date going forward.  Something like this:

```
foo.cpp: gen.py
        ./gen.py > $@.tmp
        if test -e $@ && cmp -s $@ $@.tmp; then \
            rm -f $@.tmp; \
            touch -r $@ gen.py; \
        else \
            mv -f $@.tmp $@; \
        fi
```

If you can't easily change the output filename for `gen.py` then you'll have to do something even more disgusting, like rename `$@` to `$@.old` before you run `./gen.py` then change it back or use the new one as appropriate.

*ETA* If you just want to avoid running `gen.py` if it's the same version this is more a Git question than a makefile question, because what you're really asking is how to know whether these files are in the same Git commit.  That's easy, but as my comment below says I don't think this is actually right:

```
foo.cpp: gen.py
        tver=$$(git log -n1 --oneline $@ 2>/dev/null); \
        pver=$$(git log -n1 --oneline $< 2>/dev/null); \
        if test -z "$$tver" || test -z "$$pver" || test "$$tver" != "$$pver"; then ./gen.py; fi
```

Comment: This solves a different problem entirely though: my goal is _not_ to run `gen.py` if the `gen.py` and `file.cpp` are both the same version in source control. In particular, `gen.py` may be a big complicated thing with lots of dependencies, so your average user _cannot_ run it, so the idea is to check in the generated file so they don't have to, unless they actually modify `gen.py`. This solution always runs `gen.py` even though it does it to a temporary file: it is reasonable if you want to avoid building downstream deps of `file.cpp` the first time, but I don't care about that...

Comment: It's simple enough to avoid running `gen.py` if it was pushed in the same Git commit as `foo.cpp` but that's not really right.  What if someone first modifies `gen.py` in one commit, then pushes another commit that updates `foo.cpp` with the output?  Now they're up to date, but are not the same "version" in source control.  I don't see any way to know for sure that `foo.cpp` is up to date without running `gen.py` and checking, or else making assumptions that could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't guarantee they are in sync, but the scenario you described is simply a bug: an error on the part of the person doing the checkin: you are required to check in `gen.py` and the corresponding `foo.cpp` file at the same time. It's no different than if you modified `bar.cpp` and `bar.hpp` with co-dependent changes and then checked them in one at a time: anyone who synced only the first change would have a broken or malfunctioning build. The possibility of being out of sync is one reason not to do this in the first place: you can just omit `foo.cpp` from git entirely.

Answer (score 0):

A `post-merge` hook could possibly solve your issue:

1. Add a `hooks/post-merge` script to your repository containing, e.g. (with `bash` version > 4):

   ```
   $ cat hooks/post-merge
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   printf 'running post-merge\n'
   declare -A generated=()
   generated["foo.cpp"]="gen.py"
   # add other (generated, generator) pairs to the generated associative array
   for g in "${!generated[@]}"; do
       s="${generated[$g]}"
       if ! git diff ORIG_HEAD HEAD --exit-code -- "$g" "$s" &> /dev/null; then
           printf 'touch %s\n' "$g"
           touch "$g"
       fi
   done
   $ chmod +x hooks/post-merge
   ```
2. Add a `runme.sh` script and ask your users to run it manually after they cloned the repository (they will have to really trust you but security is out of scope this answer):

   ```
   $ cat runme.sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   for s in hooks/*; do
       ln -sf ../../"$s" .git/hooks
   done
   ```

For every (`generated`, `generator`) pairs if one of the two gets modified by a git pull, the `post-merge` hook will touch `generated` such that its last modification timestamp is newer than the `generator`.

Of course, this is only a starting point, there are probably several other things to consider (rebase, ...).